# Conversion Size from Platform::String^ to char*

Tags: character-encoding, windows-runtime, c++-cli

I want to write a function that transfers a string from a Platform::String^ object to one of my own objects.  In order to do this I need to get a char* from the Platform::String^ object.  I'm not sure exactly how to determine the size of the buffer that I need however.

I am looking to do something like this:

```
void PlatStrToCustomStr(Platform::String^ source, CustomStrObject& destination)
{

    int bufferSize = (source->Length()*2)+1; //How do I know how big?
    char* buffer = new char[bufferSize]; 
    size_t* result;
    wcstombs_s(result, buffer, bufferSize, source->Begin(), bufferSize);

    destination.copy(buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```

Is there a way for me to know how big the bufferSize has to be?

I know there are other similar questions but I didn't find an answer to this specific question with code.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the reference to [`wcstombs_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7wzt4be%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you will see that the second argument can be `NULL`. You will then get the amount of bytes needed for the resulting string returned. You also need to set the third argument to zero for this to work.

---

But you have a more serious problem, in that you pass an uninitialized pointer as the first argument. You should actually declare `result` as a normal (non-pointer) variable and use the address-of operator `&` to pass the argument by reference:

```
size_t result = 0;
wcstombs_s(&result, ...);
```